# How to Send and recieve array of udp packet

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, udp

Here's what I've been trying to do:

**Common code**
//defining an array of custom class objects  CoOrdinates class is defines in both server and client (android applications)

```
 ArrayList<CoOrdinates> Loc_Positions = new ArrayList<CoOrdinates>
```

**Server side**

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(Loc_Coordinates);
final byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
socket.send(packet);
```

**client**

```
DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(buf2, buf2.length);
socket.receive(packet2);     
byte[] data = packet2.getData();
ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(baos);
Loc_Coordinates = (ArrayList<CoOrdinates>) oos.readObject();
```

*ISSUE*

//  class not found Exception

The object is send from client to server but when object is fetched on server side the (`ObjectInputStream oos`) object has null and  (Loc_Coordinates line) causes exception error.